# Simulate slow connection between two ubuntu server machines

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, tcp, bandwidth-throttling

I want to simulate the following scenario: given that I have 4 ubuntu server machines A,B,C and D. I want to reduce the network bandwidth by 20% between machine A and machine C and 10% between A and B. How to do this using network simulation/throttling tools ?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu comes with a tool called [NetEm](http://www.opensourceforu.com/2012/06/bandwidth-throttling-netem-network-emulation/). It can control most of the network layer metrics (bandwidth, delay, packetloss). There are tons of tutorials online.

[Dummynet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/) is one such tool to do it.

[KauNet](http://www.kau.se/en/kaunet) a tool developed by karlstad university, which can introduce packet level control.

Answer (score 1):

The simple program **wondershaper** fits here very well. 
Just execute:

```
sudo wondershaper eth0 1024 1024
```

It will limit your network bandwidth on the `eth0` interface to 1Mbps download and upload rate.